# How to get Current Quarter dates without hard coding?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
if(op.Country__c=='India'){
                  if((op.createddate > 01/01/2015)||(op.createddate < 31/03/2015))
                    InProjectedQ1Count = InProjectedQ1Count + 1;
              if((op.createddate > 01/04/2015)||(op.createddate < 30/06/2015))
                InProjectedQ2Count = InProjectedQ2Count + 1;
              if((op.createddate > 01/07/2015)||(op.createddate < 30/09/2015))
                InProjectedQ3Count = InProjectedQ3Count + 1;
              if((op.createddate > 01/10/2015)||(op.createddate < 31/12/2015))
                InProjectedQ4Count = InProjectedQ4Count + 1;
```

Comment: You could alternatively just get the month

Answer (score 1):

You can do other way round using just month & not the specific dates,

```
Set<Integer> Q1 = new Set<Integer>{1,2,3};
Set<Integer> Q2 = new Set<Integer>{4,5,6};
Set<Integer> Q3 = new Set<Integer>{7,8,9};
Set<Integer> Q4 = new Set<Integer>{10,11,12};

if(op.Country__c=='India'){
      Integer cMonth = op.createddate.month();
      if(Q1.contains(cMonth)){
            InProjectedQ1Count = InProjectedQ1Count + 1;}
      if(Q2.contains(cMonth)){
            InProjectedQ2Count = InProjectedQ2Count + 1;}
      if(Q3.contains(cMonth)){
            InProjectedQ3Count = InProjectedQ3Count + 1;}
      if(Q4.contains(cMonth)){
            InProjectedQ4Count = InProjectedQ4Count + 1;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the Period object. Please have a look at the following post, I think it might help you : [duplicate post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4166/how-to-get-end-date-for-current-fiscal-quarter-in-apex)

```
Select p.Type, p.SystemModstamp, p.StartDate, p.QuarterLabel, p.PeriodLabel, p.Number, p.IsForecastPeriod, p.Id, p.FiscalYearSettingsId, p.EndDate From Period p where p.Type = 'Quarter'
```