# how to check given number is which quarter+apex?

Tags: apex

when i write a trigger I have facing a issue related to quarter.
In apex code i want to check particular given date is Which Quarter.please anyone suggests...

Comment: check this out.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4166/how-to-get-end-date-for-current-fiscal-quarter-in-apex

Comment: the answer depends on whether you are using calendar year fiscal quarters or some the quarters are not based on calendar year (e.g. Q1 starts on Feb 1). You can also use formula fields for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Date.Month()` for the the month value, here you will get integer value like 1 for Jan...12 for Dec then from this value you can easily get its quarter.
Here is example for you:

```
Integer quarter = date.today().month()/3;
if(quarter == 0)
    system.debug('==FirstQuarter==';
else if(quarter == 1)
    system.debug('==SecondQuarter==');
else if (quarter == 2)
      system.debug('==ThirdQuarter==');
else 
      system.debug('==fourthQuarter==');
```

Hope this helps!!!

Regards,
Krishna

Comment: I guess that when you say `month == 0`, you mean `i==0`? That's why the variable should be named 'quarter' instead :)

Comment: yes..you are correct @mkorman

Comment: Thats incorrect, For June , it is 6. How 6/3 = 2 is third quarter?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Apex code below.

```
for (integer month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
    system.debug(month + ' = ' + math.round((month+1)/3.0));
}
```

Comment: Magic numbers? Please care to explain.

Comment: There is no magic number here. 3.0 is number of months in a quarter. When you add 1 to the month number and divide it by 3.0 (to make the expression a double data type) and round it. You get the quarter number.