# How to retrieve start date and end date for fiscal month?

Tags: date, calendar

I want to compare today date and check is it fall into which fiscal month?How to retrieve what is start date and end date of the fiscal month?

When I am google I only found fiscal year and fiscal quarter.Please let me know if this possible or not.

-----------------Updated ---------------------------------

So I use Period object to query but here some confusing data return.

1) Using THIS_MONTH

```
Select StartDate, EndDate From Period Where type = 'Month' and StartDate = THIS_MONTH
```

It returns it return StartDate=2016-11-26 , EndDate =2016-12-31 , which is our next month(December).

2) Using NEXT_MONTH
Result no data return.

3) Using LAST_MONTH
it return two rows data which are current fiscal month and previous fiscal month(October and November).

I confuse, logically it should return November for THIS_MONTH, December for NEXT_MONTH and October for LAST_MONTH,

Comment: check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4166/18731

Comment: I check just now, but this is Fiscal Quarter not month.Or am I reading it wrong ly?

Comment: is this question still open?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Period object and use type = 'Month' for current month and use StartDate = THIS_Month

```
Date closeDate = [Select EndDate From Period 
                    Where type = 'Month' and StartDate = THIS_Month].EndDate;
```

Comment: I updated the question as it will be difficult to read if I put here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using non-standard fiscal periods, you cannot get away with a native filter assumption that the current fiscal month will begin or end inside the current calendar month. For the current month, at least, you can use:

```
SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM Period
WHERE Type = 'Month'
AND StartDate <= TODAY
AND EndDate >= TODAY
```